# Comonoids in coslices of a topos

Tags: category-theory, monoid, topos-theory

Is it true that there are no nontrivial comonoids (with respect to the cocartesian monoidal structure, of course) in any coslice category of a topos?

**Proof that the answer is "Yes" for the case of** $Set$

Let $X$ be a set. Then, a comonoid in $X/Set$ consists of a set $Y$ and maps $i:X \to Y$, $p:Y \to X$ (the counit), and $m:Y \to Y \sqcup_{X} Y$ (the comultiplication) satisfying the following conditions:

- $p \circ i=1_X$
- $m \circ i$ coincides with the equal compositions of the two pushout coprojections $Y \to Y \sqcup_{X} Y$ with $i$
- Counitality: The two compositions $Y \to Y \sqcup_{X} Y \to Y$, where the first map is $m$ for both compositions and the second maps are the two maps induced by $i \circ p$ and $1_Y$ (in each order), are both equal to $1_Y$.
- Coassociativity: The two induced ternary comultiplication maps $Y \to Y \sqcup_{X} Y \sqcup_{X} Y$, namely $(m \sqcup_{X} 1_Y) \circ m$ and $(1_Y \sqcup_{X} m) \circ m$, are equal.

Now, one must prove that $i$ and $p$ must in fact be inverse bijections. In fact, only the first three conditions are needed; coassociativity is not used at all.

First, note that $Y \sqcup_X Y$ (the "amalgamated coproduct") can be seen as the quotient of $Y \times \{0,1\}$ by the equivalence relation that identifies $(y, a)$ with $(y', a')$ if $y=y'$, and either $a=a'$ or $y$ is in the image of $i$. Given this, for any $y \in Y$, $m(y)$ is an equivalence class $[(y', a)]$ where $y' \in Y$ and $a \in \{0,1\}$.

Then, one of the two maps $Y \sqcup_{X} Y \to Y$ sends $[(y', a)]$ to $i(p(y'))$ if $a=0$ and $y'$ if $a=1$, and the other map sends $[(y', a)]$ to $y'$ if $a=0$ and $i(p(y'))$ if $a=1$. Regardless of whether $a$ is $0$ or $1$, one of those two maps must send $[(y', a)]$ to $i(p(y'))$, and counitality then implies that one must have $y=i(p(y'))$.

Hence, $i \circ p$ is surjective. But it is also idempotent, so it must in fact be equal to $1_Y$. Hence, $i$ and $p$ must in fact be inverse bijections. $\square$

**General case**

Since pushouts in presheaf toposes are computed pointwise, the answer to the question continues to be "Yes" for any presheaf topos (even if one replaces "comonoid" with "counital comagma"). But I do not see how the above argument could internalize to any (elementary) topos.

Comment: As far as I can see the argument should work as is in the internal language of a topos.  (In the interpretation of the proof, I think one step would be: for any test object $U$ and any morphism $y : U \to Y$, there exist morphisms $\pi_1 : V_1 \to U$ and $\pi_2 : V_2 \to U$ such that $V_1 \sqcup V_2 \to U$ is an epimorphism; $\pi_1^*(m \circ y) : V_1 \to Y \sqcup_X Y$ factors through the first map $Y \to Y \sqcup_X Y$; and similarly $\pi_2^*(m \circ y) : V_2 \to Y \sqcup_X Y$ factors through the second map $Y \to Y \sqcup_X Y$.)

Comment: I agree with Daniel: I haven't read your proof in detail, but it's manifestly a constructive proof not using any advanced set-theoretical axioms and hence will work in any elementary topos. For an introduction to this marvelous linguistic device, I recommend Chapter VI of Moerdijk/Mac Lane *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic* or Chapter 14 of Goldblatt *Topoi: The Categorical Analysis of Logic*. I [recently wrote](https://rawgit.com/iblech/internal-methods/master/paper-filmat.pdf) a short introduction aimed at philosophers of mathematics in which you might also be interested.